# Grails3 application.groovy Dynamic Properties

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-3.0

In Grails 2, we used a in-house library to be able to dynamically set property values in our Config.groovy file. This library looked at an environment specific configuration management database and populated these values. This is an example of a configuration that worked in Grails 2

```
import com.mycompany.otherproject.ConfigurationManagement   

family {
    dynamic.property = ConfigurationManagement.getValue("dynamic.property.name", "default")
    static.proprty = "static value"
}
```

Based on the [Upgrading from Grails 2.x - Reference Documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/upgrading.html), I copied this information to application.groovy, but now I get the following error that I've been unable to resolve.

```
Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: startup failed:
script14930638938641309394273.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.mycompany.otherproject.ConfigurationManagement
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import com.mycompany.otherproject.ConfigurationManagement
   ^
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you try not to import the class, but invoke methods from `com.mycompany.otherproject.ConfigurationManagement` or it's instances? Are you sure that the class is present in your classpath?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea and If I use the import, then I can jump to the method definition. If I remove the import, then I can no longer do that and the build gives me a different error: Error occurred running Grails CLI: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.getValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Maybe I'm not running this right. I'm executing a "grails clean" from my run configurations like I did in Grails 2, but I don't think that's right. I did that earlier and it walked through the build steps, but I just set up a new run configuration for "gradle clean" and "gradle build" and now I'm getting different errors related to some unit tests and additional refactoring that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't set the property directly, but can declare a local variable and then use that value to set the property.

```
import com.mycompany.otherproject.ConfigurationManagement   

def dynamicProperty = ConfigurationManagement.getValue("dynamic.property.name", "default")

family {
    dynamic.property = dynamicProprty
    static.proprty = "static value"
}
```

Comment: Just as a heads up: we don't have any config items like this in our application.groovy, but we do have them in our runtime.groovy, and they're working exactly as your original example showed (import line, then setting the property equal to the return of some static method call).  However, our call to the method is outside of any config item block.  I think that might be the difference, as I see your dynamicProperty is set outside of the family { ... } block as well.

Comment: Correct. It definitely can't be set in the block.

Comment: I'm upgrading an application right now, so leaving comments here for anybody else who hits this in the future.  I have a string property that is inside another property block, and it DID work to wrap the whole thing in ${...}.  So GeoGriffin's first example doesn't work (as he said), but workarounds include: set the value outside your block (again, like he showed), or do something like name = "${YourClass.getProperty()}".